Speed up semantic search for large dataset with custom search function
I am building a semantic search engine for short sentences where I want to know which sentence have the more similar sentences. For that, I need to know based on a threshold on the similarity score, how many similar sentences I have for each sentence, and so I need an almost complete view of the similarities between all the sentence.
Given the quality of my free text, I'm not able to achieve good performances by only using a classical transformer embedding. To get the best out of my data composed both of free texts and metadata, I have come up with an hybrid solution using sentence transformer embedding, TD-IDF embedding, and an encoding of my metadata.
Once the free texts is embedded, I perform a custom search function where I use weights to combine the cosine similarity between the sentence transformer embeddings, the cosine similarity between the TF-IDF embedding, and a pairwise matching between my encoding of metadata.
However, my dataset is quite large with more than 500k documents. The compute for the embeddings is not a problem in terms of ressources, but the search function is. As I'm not able to store a 500k*500k matrix containing all the similarity scores between all my documents, I have tried to do it by smaller batches, for example computing 100*500k matrix one after the other. This solve the memory issue, but the processing time is really high.
I have looked a bit about packages libraries such as chromadb and faiss, but it seems that they don't provide custom search features.
Any idea?

take a look at KD-trees, or something similar, this may be good start, but not sure: https://sachaarbonel.medium.com/how-to-build-a-semantic-search-engine-in-rust-e96e6378cfd9

Ty for your comment, the "problem" with such algorithm is that I haven't find a method to combine the multiple embeddings in order to compute only one similarity score (and not a combined one). However, I am actually looking at reranking methods such as RRF
